# Date is calculated wrong

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, date

I have a simple code that sets the dates `(DD/MM/YYYY)` of a month to a `Column` in `Excel`:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(int.Parse(year.Text), int.Parse(month.Text), 1); //year.Text & month.Text are just the month and year from controls in the form.
for (int j = 7; j < daysInMonth + 7; j++)
{
        sheet.get_Range("A" + j).Value = date.ToShortDateString();
        date.AddDays(1.0);
}
```

The result of that is:
01/01/2015
01/02/2015
01/03/2015
01/04/2015
01/05/2015
01/06/2015
01/07/2015
01/08/2015
01/09/2015
01/10/2015
01/11/2015
01/12/2015
13/01/2015
14/01/2015
15/01/2015
...
So, only 1 through 12 is problematic.
**Edit:**

```
int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(int.Parse(year.Text), int.Parse(month.Text));
```

Comment: Can you try date.ToOADate() ?

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster You mean to replace .ToShortDateString() with .ToOADate()?

Comment: can you provide a bit more code? from where you create the sheet, the daysInMonth variable and also provide Textbox inputs.

Comment: @FarhanAnam What do you mean by "Textbox inputs"?

Comment: what do you input in the year and month textboxes which yield the incorrect results?

Comment: @FarhanAnam How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: tell us what you enter in the form as month and year or if is already set, tell us those values.

Comment: @FarhanAnam I input 2 numbers: one for month and one for year. For the test I've input 1 for month and 2015 for year.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93309/discussion-between-farhan-anam-and-android).

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you do not update the date after every iteration of the for-loop. I mean you are doing this the wrong way:

> ```
> date.AddDays(1.0); //This returns a value but you never assign it to the date itself.
> ```

You should use something like this:

```
date = date.AddDays(1.0);
```

**UPDATE:** The above part was a slight problem with your code. The main problem is with Excel itself. When you pass it a date with the day below 13, it confuses whether it is the month or the day, regardless of the format you provide to it.

**Workaround:** Excel stores dates as the number of days after 1st Jan 1900 ([Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Convert-dates-stored-as-text-to-dates-8df7663e-98e6-4295-96e4-32a67ec0a680)). So you can set the values of the cell according to that format and then change the number format of the cell to something like you would usually set as a format - "DD/MM/YYYY".

**The function to get the integer value from the date:**

```
private int convertDateTime(DateTime input)
{
    DateTime start = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
    return (int)(input - start).TotalDays + 2; //This is some calibration with the above mentioned Office article
}
```

**Now, you can use your code like this:**

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(int.Parse(year.Text), int.Parse(month.Text), 1); //year.Text & month.Text are just the month and year from controls in the form.
for (int j = 7; j < daysInMonth + 7; j++)
{
    Range cell = sheet.get_Range("A" + j);
    cell.Value = convertDateTime(date);
    cell.NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY";
    date = date.AddDays(1.0);
}
```

Comment: ok wait a minute. I was testing this with a message box. let me reproduce the error with excel interop.

Comment: @AnDrOiD I want to ask something : When you run the app, does the Excel app also open?

Comment: No, it only creates the file.

Comment: See updated answer. It is now guaranteed to work. :-)

Comment: I really hope it'll work! (I'll try in a few minutes). In your explanation you wrote 1990 but in the code you wrote 1900. Which one is it?

Comment: it's 1900. I'll fix that

Answer (score 2):

Try counting the cell location inside the the loop and increase the date before setting it to the sheet like this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(int.Parse(year.Text), int.Parse(month.Text), 1);
for (int j = 0; j < daysInMonth; j++)
{
   // Skip increasing the first date
   if (j > 0) {
      date = date.AddDays(1.0);
   }

   // Set the correct date to the sheet
   sheet.get_Range("A" + (j + 7)).Value = date.ToString(@"dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: There is no problem with the increment. For some reason the date format is weird from the 1st day to the 12th day, and then it's ok.

Comment: You mean add .ToString() to the .Text?

Comment: No... still the same :\